# MVC Razor view debugging problems mapping incorrect files (PDB generation bug?!)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I've been having an issue with MVC 5.2.3 (and earlier versions back to about 4) using Razor (VB.NET) views where

1) I can't reliably set breakpoints inside a View (doesn't work most of the time even if VS doesn't give me a warning that it couldn't bind, which it often does)

2a) When it hits an exception within a View, the debugger often opens the wrong file (can inspect values fine though!)

2b) Examining the stack trace for the exception shows the wrong file!

3) Occasionally an exception thrown within a View doesn't resolve to any View file at all and the debugger just says it can't find the source and the stack trace doesn't show any file

I've had this on multiple computers running VS2013 and 2015 on Windows 7 and 10.  I'm just using the default routes that were set up with the original project template.  This has been going on for probably a couple of years now.  I think it is affecting multiple projects, but I've mostly been concentrating on one recently so can't remember for sure.

Sample stack trace - note the "no relevant source lines" and the "OperationsMatrix.vbhtml" which is underlined - there is no reason that view should be included and it definitely isn't rendering if there is no exception!  The correct view is "AnalyticsReport.vbhtml" (line 122) which is being partially rendered from within "SalesAnalytics.vbhtml" (at line 108).  The debugger is also incorrectly opening "OperationsMatrix.vbhtml" on an irrelevant line (the only thing on that line is an End Sub for a lambda method).: 
[image: stack trace]

I've had a look in the temp file it is referencing in the stack trace and that seems to be just be referring to OperationsMatrix.vbhtml, so that file seems to be wrong too, but it doesn't actually seem to be executing that, because I can fix the bug in AnalyticsReport.vbhtml and the exception stops occurring.

After changing some code and changing it back again (ie. effectively the same code), it is now generating the following:

[image: two]

Note that there is now source code referenced at the top (from the wrong file - LiveStock.vbhtml) and that file is now appearing near the top of the stack trace instead of one not being found.  Lower down, OperationsMatrix seems to have disappeared and it can't seem to find anything for that one.  I am pretty sure that the top one should be AnalyticsReport and the lower one should be SalesAnalytics.  I'm pretty sure that it should be mapping to Layout.vbhtml as well, which doesn't seem to be working in either of these tries (not noticed/can't remember if it ever does).  It seems to be fairly consistent in terms of it either doesn't find anything or it finds another file in the same folder.

I've just had another look at the generated files in the temp folder for that second stack trace.  App_Web_grga51wc.3.vb appears to be for a different file and App_Web_grga51wc.1.vb seems to be the one for _Layout.vb.  The file refs in the #ExternalChecksum and #ExternalSource directives appear to be correct, so I don't think that the problem is in the code generation or mapping the code from the generated file back to the original using the #ExternalSource directives.  The problem seems to be that it is mapping the IL compiled code back to the wrong generated source file (presumably a problem with the PDB file?).  I have no idea how or why this is happening, or why it seems to only be affecting MVC projects and nothing else.

For absolute clarification, the views which are being returned are apparently random from the same folder and are not referenced in any way by the view with the bug causing the exception.  They are generally not designed to be partial views and often it wouldn't make sense to use them as a partial view - they are usually full, unrelated views which are designed to be used completely independently of the one which is being called.

I've also tried deleting the whole temp folder that it is using and obviously clean and rebuild etc.  Also tried disabling the VS profiling tools.

nb. there is no consistency with which view is incorrectly opening.  A different one was being opened when I had a slightly different exception a few minutes earlier.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you give some concrete examples?  Like screenshots or a copy/paste of the Razor view line that's blowing up, the file that is opened, and the stacktrace?

Comment: I've updated it.  The view source line is irrelevant though - happens pretty much any time I hit an exception within a view.

Comment: It looks like your `row` on line 44 might be nullable.  If it is null, that could be your problem because you'd be doing an if check on a null value without checking that the value isn't null first.

Comment: That's not the issue - I can fix the exception.  The problem is that it isn't in that file and that file isn't even running!  I can be pretty definite about that, because a) I can fix it in the correct file, b) There is no reason it should be running that file, c) It doesn't match the stack trace and d) It is more or less random which file comes up there - both of these stack traces were from identical code raising the same exception!

Comment: And the offending file isn't rendered in the erroring file?  Like as a partialview.

Comment: Nope.  Just for context - I've been coding for 27 years, 17 professionally and about 12 full time.  I've been using .NET for about 13 or 14 years and MVC/Razor for nearly 3 years.  I'm generally the one who other coders ask when they get stuck, so this isn't likely to be an easy answer.

Comment: When you build your solution in debug, do you see any warnings or errors displayed in the output window involving the creation or binding of your .pdb files, specifically for those pages?

Comment: No, but I finally got to the bottom of it - see answer below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally worked it out!

In the web.config file for the site (the root one, not the one in the Views folder) the \ had an attribute as follows: -

```
assemblyPostProcessorType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspPerformanceInstrumenter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

I have removed this attribute and it seems to be debugging fine now!  It looks like VS2013 added this when I initially created the project and it has been corrupting the DLLs/PDBs that are generated and messing up the debugging.

To clarify, if anyone else has the problem, the compilation opening tag now just looks like

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```